# Kafka: In what situation will message for a topic be out of order, if order for each partition is preserved

Tags: apache-kafka

The author of the article "Kafka in a Nutshell" (at https://sookocheff.com/post/kafka/kafka-in-a-nutshell/) states that:

> Kafka makes the following guarantees about data consistency and availability: (1) Messages sent to a topic partition will be appended to the commit log in the order they are sent, (2) a single consumer instance will see messages in the order they appear in the log, (3) a message is ‘committed’ when all in sync replicas have applied it to their log, and (4) any committed message will not be lost, as long as at least one in sync replica is alive.
>
> The first and second guarantee ensure that message ordering is preserved for each partition. Note that message ordering for the entire topic is not guaranteed. ...

I'm curious as to what the author meant when he said:

> Note that message ordering for the entire topic is not guaranteed.

Comment: If you have several consumers for a topic, one can process is messages faster than the other, so following messages in its partition will be handled earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka topic consists of multiple partitions where message get appended to each partition based on key hashing or partitioner rule (random, round-robin, custom, etc.)

Topic partition basically parallelize process by distributing message across partition

Hence Kafka guarantee order on each partition but since message gets distributed across partition we can not guarantee order globally or per topic
[image]

As above diagram producer publishing message to the topic but it gets appended sequentially to any of the partition hence

```
E.g. assume partition selection is a round-robin

    message 1 -> publish to p1 in position 1
    message 2 -> publish to p2 in position 1
    message 3 -> publish to p2 in position 3
    message 4 -> publish to p1 in position 2
    message 5 -> publish to p2 in position 2
```

and so on
so consumers can consumer messages but could not be in the same order as producers.

If you want to have a global ordering, you will need to have only 1 partition.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation. However, my understanding is that each message will be replicated across partitions. So in your example above, after `message 1 -> publish to p1 in position 1`, message 1 will be replicated to p2 and p3. Only after that will `message 2 -> publish to p2...` happen. I'm assuming message 2 must is published after the replication because if it were otherwise, then the order within p2 is also not guaranteed.

Comment: replication not happend across partition but across broker...means p1 replicated to p1 in broker 2.

Comment: Thanks. I previous conflated partitions and replication. Now I understand that each topic may be split into multiple partitions, and each partition will be replicated.